# How to set border dynamically?

Tags: three.js

I'm currently using Three.JS, I would like to set border dynamically depends on the lot plan.

I'm planning to have a dynamic function with square-meter parameters for that but since I'm not familiar using Three.JS I don't know how to start it.

I tried to use splineCurve, CubicBezierCurve but it didn't work out.

Here's what I did.

[image]

```
import * as THREE from '/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

function main(){
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#homeqube');
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
    const fov = 45;
    const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 100;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
    controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
    controls.update();

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

    {
        const planeSize = 40;
    
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        const repeats = planeSize / 2;
        texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);
    
        const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
        const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          map: texture,
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        });
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
        mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
        mesh.position.y = -0.55;
        scene.add(mesh);

      }

      {
        const skyColor = 0xB1E1FF;  // light blue
        const groundColor = 0xB97A20;  // brownish orange
        const intensity = 1;
        const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
        scene.add(light);
      }
    
      {
        const color = 0xFFFFFF;
        const intensity = 1;
        const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
        light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
        scene.add(light);
        scene.add(light.target);
      }

    
      function addXYZCube(boxWitdh, boxHeight, boxDepth,Xposition,Yposition, Zposition){
        const color = 0x750C09;
        let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWitdh,boxHeight,boxDepth);
        let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});
        let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
        cube.position.y = Yposition;
        cube.position.x = Xposition;
        cube.position.z = Zposition; 
        scene.add(cube);
      } 
  


  function setCubicBezierCurve(){
    const curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
      new THREE.Vector3( 15, 0, 0 ),
       new THREE.Vector3( 0, -50, 0 ),
      new THREE.Vector3( -40, -5, 0 ),
      new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    );

const points = curve.getPoints( 5 );
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
const splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
splineObject.rotation.x = Math.PI * .5;
splineObject.position.y = 0.05;
splineObject.position.z = 4;
scene.add(splineObject);
}

setCubicBezierCurve();



      function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        const width = canvas.clientWidth;
        const height = canvas.clientHeight;
        const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
        if (needResize) {
          renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
        }
        return needResize;
      }

      function render() {
        if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
          const canvas = renderer.domElement;
          camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }
    
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
      }
    
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
}

main();
```

this is example of expected result.

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a curve class, have you tried to directly create a geometry via `setFromPoints()` with the given points?

Comment: I didn't tried it. May I see your approach?

Comment: Check out: https://jsfiddle.net/gxhn59oq/1/